# How do I change colour of an upload button after exceeding maximum number of file uploads?

Tags: html, css, angular, button, file-upload

I have this line in my HTML file to limit the number for file uploads to maximum = 3.

```
<input *ngIf="uploader.queue.length < 3" #uploadButton ng2FileSelect
       (change)="fileUpload()" [uploader]="uploader" id="supporting-doc-type-{{docType}}"
       type="file"
       class="upload-button"/>
<label for="supporting-doc-type-{{docType}}" *ngIf="uploader.queue.length < 3" class="fake-upload-button" >
  {{'account.uploadNric.uploadDoc'| translate}}
</label>
```

For now, it works okay where the upload button disappears once user uploaded the maximum number of files. But now, I want to make the button changes color from blue to red instead of making it just disappears. How do I do that?

Full CSS file:

```
.upload-button {
  display: none;
}

.fake-upload-button {
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #29b6f6;
  padding: 4px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.col, .col-1, .col-10, .col-11, .col-12, .col-2, .col-3, .col-4, .col-5, .col-6, .col-7, .col-8, .col-9, .col-lg, .col-lg-1, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-md, .col-md-1, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-sm, .col-sm-1, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-xl, .col-xl-1, .col-xl-10, .col-xl-11, .col-xl-12, .col-xl-2, .col-xl-3, .col-xl-4, .col-xl-5, .col-xl-6, .col-xl-7, .col-xl-8, .col-xl-9 {
  padding: 0;
}

.trash-can-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind disable attribute of input to expression "uploader.queue.length >= 3"

```
<input
  #uploadButton
  id="supporting-doc-type-{{docType}}"
  type="file"
  class="upload-button"
  [disabled]="uploader.queue.length >= 3"
/>
```

And in css use selector

```
input:disabled + .fake-upload-button {
  background-color: red;
}
```

[example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-epaw6m?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 1):

To disable the input field try changing your *ngIf with:

```
<input [attr.disabled]="uploader?.queue.length < 3 ? null : ''"/>
```

To change the color of the input button when it should be disabled add a conditional class to your input field:

```
<input [class.inactive]="!(uploader?.queue.length < 3)"/>
```

With some CSS styling:

```
.inactive{
    background-color: red;
}
```

The question mark after uploader checks if it exists.

Comment: Yes, this seems to work but I don't know how to add a conditional class to my input field. Could you pls show me how you'd do it? `<input [attr.disabled]="uploader?.queue.length < 3 ? null : ''"
       [class.inactive]="!(uploader?.queue.length < 3) #uploadButton ng2FileSelect
       (change)="fileUpload()" [uploader]="uploader" id="supporting-doc-type-{{docType}}"
       type="file" class="upload-button"/>`

Comment: The [class.inactive]="conditionValue" is the conditional class. You can change it with [class.upload-button-inactive] where the '.upload-button-inactive' class is only added when conditionValue is true.